# specify type of keyof target

Tags: typescript, keyof

Is there any way to specify the type of object a `keyof` is pointing to?

So that, for example:

```
type MyType = { a: string, b: number };
let myKey: keyof<string> MyType = "a"; // Valid
myKey = "b"; // Invalid
```

And then, when you use:

```
let myVar: MyType = { a: "Hello", b: 1 };
funcThatNeedsAString(MyType[myKey]);
```

it already knows that `MyType[myKey]` is a string?

Comment: On mobile now but I usually call this `KeysMatching` and this question is likely a duplicate of some question mentioning that term.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Of course my syntax isn't valid. I am using the `keyof<string>` as a stand-in for what I want to happen.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, thanks